# Bridge Movie Night 5: The Bridge Strikes Back

Tags: discussion, community-event

I know it's been awhile, we seem to have skipped a month. But don't worry, nothing's changed. I realize that we ran into a few problems with Rabb.it the last time around, supposedly they were going through some growing pains. Hopefully, our break will have given them enough time to make things stable again. Things should proceed as normal, please check in 
on [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) the night of your preferred showing as I will try to find alternatives should Rabb.it not be available.

- Date: August 1-2 (Saturday, Sunday) at 11:00 PM UTC-0.
- Location: [Bridge Theatre Room](https://rabb.it/yuuki) (spillover rooms will be provided as necessary)

Please post your movie suggestions below. A decision will be reached roughly a week before the showing. While we welcome any movie suggestion, a movie that is available for streaming (either through Netflix, Google Play, Amazon Prime, etc.) is much preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Movie Decision

[image: empty space]

## Ernest and Celestine

[image: Ernest and Celestine]]

Showings will begin on **Saturday, August 1** at **11:00 PM UTC-0**. We will run subsequent showings as needed/requested. A reminder event will be posted to the Bridge chatroom and there should be chat announcements 5-10 minutes before each showing begins. If there are subsequent showings, they will take place after a 10-15 minute intermission. Should you miss the Saturday showing, please put in a request via the Bridge chatroom for a Sunday night showing, which will ostensibly begin at the same time.

As always, moviegoers are encouraged to use the Rabbit chat features to talk about the movie, though spoilers are strongly discouraged as there may be people watching for the first time.

Answer (score 8):

### Movie Suggestion: *ERNEST & CÉLESTINE*

[image: ERNEST & CÉLESTINE]

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1816518/plotsummary):

> There is a world of where the Bears live above ground in their cities and the rodents live below in in their underground ones in mutual fear and hate. However, Celestine, an apprentice mouse dentist, finds at least momentary common cause with Ernest, a poor street Bear musician, that gets them rejected from both their respective worlds. In spite of this misfortune, the exiles find a growing friendship between themselves as their respective talents flower because of it. Despite this, their quietly profound challenge to the founding prejudices of their worlds cannot be ignored as the authorities track them down. When that happens, Ernest and Celestine must stand up for their love in the face of such bigotry and achieve the impossible.

[**Trailer**](https://youtu.be/PyU-mSUOnSs) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**97%/88%**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/ernest_and_celestine/) | Advisory: [**PG**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1816518/parentalguide) | Runtime: **80 minutes**

Availability: [**Amazon Prime**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L23PFDG)

Comment: This looks absolutely fantastic. It looks like The Iron Giant is going to win this one, but you should definitely suggest it again for the next movie night, because it looks great.

Answer (score 3):

### Movie Suggestion: The Iron Giant

[image: The Iron Giant]

Hogarth Hughes is a nine-year-old boy living in the small sleepy town of Rockwell, Maine. Shortly after the Russians launch Sputnik into orbit, Hogarth makes a startling discovery: we are not alone in the universe. He meets and befriends a giant robot. But things don't stay peaceful. It *is* 1957 after all, near the height of the Cold War. The Iron Giant's landing didn't go unnoticed.

*The Iron Giant* is a story about friendship and that the choices we make, not how we look, determines who we are.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgjmFBX34zc) | [Rotten Tomatoes (96%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/iron_giant/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0129167/parentalguide)

Comment: Iron Giant is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Movie Suggestion: Despicable Me

[image: Despicable Me]

Gru is the world's greatest supervillain. Well, at least he was until someone stole the Great Pyramid of Giza. Showoff. In a bid to get back to the top, Gru decides to make the biggest heist in human history: stealing the moon. Of course, to do so, he'll need to get his hands on a shrink ray. And it just so happens that the best chance of getting his hands on one lies in the hands of three orphaned girls: Margo, Edith, and Agnes.

Now, Gru has to balance his career as the (former) world's greatest supervillain and his new life as a sort-of-quasi-father to three girls.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUkZFetWYY0) | [Rotten Tomatoes (81%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/1214097-despicable_me/) | [IMDB Parental Guide (Rated PG)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1323594/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Answer (score 2):

### Iron Man

[image: Iron Man]

See the movie that started it all. Tony Stark is a genius billionaire playboy philanthropist (not necessarily in that order). Owner and CEO of Stark Industries, America's top defense contractor, Tony is caught in an ambush while demonstrating one of his newest weapons, attacked by fighters using his own weapons. Kidnapped by the regional militants, Tony is held for ransom and forced to build weapons for the terrorist ring. Defiant, he builds an armored suit in secret and uses it to escape and fight evil.

[Trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWWd6p2JHKo) | [Rotten Tomatoes (94%)](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/iron_man/) | [Parental Guide (Rated PG-13)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/parentalguide?ref_=tt_ql_7)

Answer (score 2):

### Movie Suggestion: *The Room*

[image: The Room]

From [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368226/plotsummary):

> In San Francisco, we follow Johnny, a man who has a girlfriend, Lisa, and also his best friend, Mark. Lisa has been cheating on Johnny with Mark and Johnny doesn't know! Will Johnny ever find out? Will Mark still be Johnny's best friend?.

[**Trailer**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCj8sPCWfUw) | Tomato/Audience Score: [**35%/46%**](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_room_1998/) | Advisory: [**R**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368226/parentalguide) | Runtime: **99 minutes**

Comment: Sin Count: 1,591,985,490 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvuwldnG7c0

Comment: On one hand, this movie shouldn't be inflicted on anyone else. On the other, I wish more people knew what was going on when I said "YOU'RE TEARING ME APART, LISA"